# Auto populating Google Calendar based on Google Sheets document

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar, google-sheets

I've read a lot of posts related to my problem... The problem is I'm not a computer programmer and it's like reading a foreign language to me.  I've tried to muddle my way through it but to no avail.  I've mainly been working from [this post](http://blog.ouseful.info/2010/03/04/maintaining-google-calendars-from-a-google-spreadsheet/) and the links from that page.

I have a Google Sheets document with a list of id numbers and a start date and end date for treatments.  I'd like to be able to run a script that will auto populate a Google Calendar with the id numbers as the event title and the treatment time frame.  I don't need a start and end time, I'm only looking for dates.

I would also like to create another Google Calendar from the same spreadsheet.  I have 6 columns associated with each id number - a projected date and an actual date for 3 different types of testing.  I would like to be able to run another script that populates a Google Calendar with the type of testing as the event title.  Again, not concerned with times at all, just the dates.

I'm using this to track an experiment I'm running and it's just a lot of information to see on a spreadsheet.  It would be nice easier to see all the testing I need to do in a calendar format so I don't make any more mistakes in missing testing days or when to stop treatments.

I've been trying for 3 weeks to figure this out on my own.  Let's just say, I know nothing about coding...

Comment: You might get lucky and get someone to write the code for you if you leave some contact details in your profile.

Answer (score 0):

You should try writing a function in Google Apps script.

1. Get the active [sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getActiveSheet()), get [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)) and retreive the id numbers and a start date and end date.
2. Then create a calender event by referring to this [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event).

Hope that helps!